# Sparse multidimensional array replacement in Java

Tags: java, optimization, data-structures, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

I have a java project in which I'm currently using huge multidimensional arrays of floats (usually 8-12 dimensions with each dimension varying in size from 2-50) to store data that is generated by the program. The program both reads from and writes to the arrays millions of times, so I need a data structure that has extremely fast access times (like the O(1) time for arrays). But the arrays are somewhat sparse and I'm running into RAM constraints, so I'm wondering if there are any other data structure options that would be better for storing sparse data but would not slow down the access/write times much.

Comment: A hash whose keys are based on the indexes?

Comment: Could use some more context. For example the well known "sorted index/data pairs" scheme works really well if you iterate over it, not so well if you want to index into it randomly. So it matters how exactly you use it.